# Tempdb. There is no enough space on the disc encountered

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, tempdb

Does anyone know what really happened here?

All of the sudden database was not accessible.

How to find transactions that cause tempdb filled up?

Seems like it happened right after SQL profiler trace has stopped. Can this cause the issue?

[image]

Comment: Profiler has nothing to do with this error. The session that opened that transaction was alive until 11:58:10 when it was rolled back. There is no way now to find out what code was executing to cause that error

Comment: If this caused an application query to fail, there might be some helpful information in the log file of the application.  I'm not too optimistic that you'l  find anything helpful, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: It's hard to tell what caused this to happen, but I would recommend executing dmv queries to find out what used the space and why (sys.dm_db_file_space_usage and sys.dm_db_session_space_usage):  
SELECT top (5) *
FROM sys.dm_db_session_space_usage
ORDER BY (user_objects_alloc_page_count + internal_objects_alloc_page_count) DESC